# How to not crash when a socket fails to connect

Tags: sockets, networking, rust, error-handling

I am building a bitcoin clone that needs to be able to connect to other sockets and send information between them. How do I try to connect to another socket and if the socket doesn't respond just continue with the code instead of crashing the whole program?

This is kind of what I think the code would look like:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main()
{
    for node in nodes {
        let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(node).unwrap();
        if successful_connection {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `unwrap()`. From [its docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap):

> Panics if the value is an [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err), with a panic message provided by the [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err)’s value.

This function's purpose is to abort your program if the operation has failed, and so:

> Because this function may panic, its use is generally discouraged. Instead, prefer to use pattern matching and handle the [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err) case explicitly, or call [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or), [`unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_else), or [`unwrap_or_default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_default).

In case you want to do something only if the operation has succeeded, and do nothing in the other case, [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html) is your best friend:

```rust
if let Ok(stream) = TcpStream::connect(node) {
    // Do something with `stream`
}
```

If you also want to handle the error case, you can use [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match.html):

```rust
match TcpStream::connect(node) {
    Ok(stream) => {
        // Do something with `stream`
    }
    Err(error) => {
        // Handle the error
    }
}
```